# How to store User Data in Context and using it on other Components - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

How can I store the current logged in user data in context and use them in other components without having to call the user api on every component to show the data, for example `{user.firstname}`

I have this coming from the `http://localhost:8000/api/me`

```
"status": 200,
"user": {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Makomere",
    "email": "makomere@john.com",
    "phone": "788998878",
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "role": 0,
    "image": null,
    "bio": null,
    "county_id": null,}
```

But every time I want to show the data on  component, I have to use this code:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {

    let isMounted = true;

    axios.get(`/api/me`).then(res => {
        if (isMounted) {
            if (res.data.status === 200) {
                setUser(res.data.user);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        }
    });
    return () => {
        isMounted = false
    };
}, []);
```

Kindly help. Thank you

Comment: You can use redux or other state management libraries. Or just use context API that is built in ReactJS that can help you to handle global states. Also, you might build a custom hook.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read context docs: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

```
import React from 'react';

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {

const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

useEffect(() =>{
  axios.get(...)
   .(...)
  .then(data =>{
    setUser(data)
  }
}, [])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
      <User />
      ...
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then you can read the user data from any component inside UserContext.Provider

```
function User() {
  const user = React.useContext(UserContext);  
    
  return <h1>{user.firstname}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: This is not supposed to be an answer.